# How can I change background image in 1 second for only one time

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to change my background only one time after 1 second of loading. Then Second Image will be show.

I just want to show the first image only for 1st one second then want to show second image.

**HTML**

```
<div id="image-head" class="image-head">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-head {
  background-image:url(background_image_1.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
}
```

**JS**

```
var images = [
  "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/background_image_2.jpg"
]

var imageHead = document.getElementById("image-head");
var i = 1;

setInterval(function() {
      imageHead.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
      i = i + 1;
      if (i == images.length) {
        i =  0;
      }
}, 1000);
```

Please let me know how can I do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Use setTimeout to run the function only once. setInterval will run every second until it's cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

And you don't even need that array

```
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("image-head").style.backgroundImage = `url("http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/background_image_2.jpg")`, 1000);
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
setInterval(function() {
      imageHead.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
      i = i + 1;
      if (i == images.length) {
        i =  0;
      }
}, 1000);
```

by

```
setTimeout(function() {
      imageHead.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
      i = i + 1;
      if (i == images.length) {
        i =  0;
      }
}, 1000);
```

> The setInterval() method, offered on the Window and Worker interfaces, repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. It returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the interval, so you can remove it later by calling clearInterval().
>
> The setTimeout() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin (and successor to Window.setTimeout()) sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.

See [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

@DominikMatis has the correct answer, but I wanted to help clean the code up a bit.

```
var image = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/background_image_2.jpg";

var imageHead = document.getElementById("image-head");

setTimeout(function() {
      imageHead.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + image + ")";
}, 1000);
```

This makes more sense since you're only replacing the image once, with a single image. What you had before would work great for replacing several images at a specified time interval.